# how do I find number of numbers having product of its digits and sum of its digits both equal to given number N

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, factoring, prime-factorization, decimal-expansion

I want algorithm for a big given $N<10^5$ , say for $4$ ,we have numbers $22$ and $4$ only .I approached it in this way :
Say we have $12$ as $N$ , then if it is prime and one digit then return $1$ else $0$ . If not then find all the ways in which $12$ can be written as it's factors' product like $2\times 2\times 3$ so in the number we can have $22311111$ now find it's all permutations then do it for $4\times 3$ so -> $4311111$ find it's permutations then $2\times 6$ we have $261111$ find it's permutations  and finally add all the permutations and return it.
For a small number I have it's factors $\{2,3,4,6\}$ but how do I get it's factor combinations and there occurrences so that I can add $1$s and find their (factors) permutations with 1s efficiently?

Comment: Algorithmic implementation or design questions should generally be asked in StackOverflow, as suggested by the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This question is *very* confusing; could you try to rephrase it? Don't worry about your English grammar: as long as you make your meaning clear, someone can edit it so it's grammatically correct.

Comment: How many numbers  do exist such that sum of their digits and product of their digits are equal to a given number N

Comment: I believe this is a Project Euler question, number 88. I don't recall the site policy on answering these sorts of things though. This should at least be tagged as such.

Comment: It's a question on SPOJ , what's project Euler?

Comment: Problem name is ADADIG on SPOJ